# PyCharm creating executable file, ImportError: Failed to import any qt binding for QT interface

Tags: python, pycharm, pyqt5

I have followed the solution in the post title ImportError: Failed to import any qt binding, Python - Tensorflow to solve my executable file error

```
File "matplotlib/backends/qt_compat.py", line 168, in <module>
ImportError: Failed to import any qt binding
[10262] Failed to execute script AI_DES_CONDA
```

But the solution of reinstalling matplotlib with updated pip didn't work in my case

I have used pyinstaller to create the executable file using the following command:

```
pyinstaller --onefile AI_DES_CONDA.py
```

Python used in creating the file and interface is 3.7.5
 The libraries used are:

```
import time
import time
import os
import csv
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg
#matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from sklearn import model_selection
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.discriminant_analysis import LinearDiscriminantAnalysis
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn import tree
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
import pickle
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import seaborn as sb
import warnings
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
```

Please see image for more details:
[image]

Note: I am using pycharm to create the executable file.

Any advice?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got an error like that. re-install is a way but there might be more than one package at the path with same name.
i.e. if there is numpy-stl and stl in the same path we might get that error. 
by the way you should pip3 to install `pip3 install mathplotlib`